# "Sorted by" dropdown is further right-aligned than the answer area on Q&A pages

Tags: bug, design, sorting

The sorted by dropdown is not aligned with the rest of the answers page:

[image: Screenshot of example Q&A page, showing that right end of "Sorted by dropdown" is further right than the right side of answer area.]

You should add the class `post-layout--right` to the `<div class="answers-subheader d-flex ai-center mb8">` div directly inside the `<div id="answers-header">` div to align the right corner of the "Sorted by" dropdown with the rest of the answers page.

Right now it looks sloppy.